# Performance of Before, After hooks in cucumber testing

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I have multiple tear setup/down steps performed in beforeAll and AfterAll block. How do I get the performance of these two steps. Basically, how much time is it taking for the complete BeforeAll step to complete.

One simple way is to have a timer and then do startTime-endTime, however, I was hoping to find some existing way through cucumber. Does something like this exist?